# Import ArcToolbox Log History on ArcGis

Tags: arcgis-desktop, geoprocessing, arctoolbox, log, results

I do not know what  happened but I have lost all my ArcToolbox log history that was available trough "Results" menu.

The strange thing is that I can access the log files that are saved on my harddrive. Those files are on .xml format but I do not know how to import them back to the "Results" history menu. In this picture you can see that I have very few logs in the "Results" history, but I have all of the history files!

[image]

Is there any way I can import back these files to the "Results" menu?

Can someone give me a help on this? To me is extremely useful to see the results history! It helps me a lot!

Comment: If you're talking arcmap as opposed to catalog, the results should stay with the mxd that was open when they were run--if the mxd was saved.

Comment: I'm talking about arcmap! I know the results should stay with the mxd, but the problem is that they are gone! But although they are gone in the arcmap, they are available from the .xml files! What I really want to know is how can I import them back to the "Results" menu!

Answer (score 1):

I suspect this is an issue with your geo-processing environment settings. Have you gone into that and changed it? If you go into that (Geoprocessing > Geoprocessing Options...) look at what your *Results Management* say. If you've never changed that then you will have accepted the default of 2 Weeks.

If you read the help page *[Using geoprocessing options to control tool execution](http://help.arcgis.com/En/Arcgisdesktop/10.0/Help/index.html#//00210000000q000000)* it discusses what this means and the implications of extending the time period.

Comment: You are right. I have never changed those definitions on the "Geoprocessing Options". It remains the default settings of "2 Weeks". Now I understand why the results were gone!

But I really wanted to get them back again! Is there any way I can convert the .xml result files to .rlt so that I can add them on the "shared" results?